# Accessing list of lists inside a for

Tags: scala

I have the following bit of code in scala which is not working:

```
 var tacTable : List[List[TACList]] = List(List())

  def gen(p: Program) = {
    for (i <- 0 to p.classes.length){
      for (j <- 0 to p.classes(i).methods.length){
        var tacInstr = new TACList()
        tacTable(i)(j) = tacInstr //error: application does not take parameters
      }
    }
  }
```

Apparently, it has to do with the fact that I'm using j to access the list and j is used in for...how can I solve this?

For convenience you can work with this other example which gives the same error:

```
var l : List[List[Int]] = List(List(1,2),List(3,4))
for (i <- 0 to l.length) {
  for (j <- 0 to l.length) {
    l(i)(j) = 8
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE] of your problem?

Comment: Probably because `List` is immutable and you can't `update` it in place. Use a `mutable.ListBuffer` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists are immutable.
Try this instead:

```
 val tacTable  = p.classes.map { _.methods.map { _ =>
     new TACList()
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

since I cannot comment on the initial post a sidenote here:

in a scala for-comprehension you can use multiple generators in a single for. so the nesting that you used is not necessary since you can use this:

```
for (i <- 0 to l.length; j <- 0 to l.length) {
  // your code
}
```

furthermore, this does not seem to apply in your case but if you had a flat mapped result you should use the yield of the for comprehension instead of a mutation in the body